# Php submitting solution needed

Tags: php, cookies, curl

ok i have edited the script and let me tell you that u am a newbie in php

and as far as problem is concern i think either its cookie problem or session problem

but i really dont know how to use them correctly!!

here is page 1 named cap.php- http://pastebin.com/ZHE0BJku

here is page 2 named play.php- http://pastebin.com/1VNgMEcQ

Comment: if(!stristr($dt,"mywallet.php")) ...may be this is the problem because stristr only Search a string.

Comment: You should give part of the code that is causing the issue instead of providing your complete code.

Comment: sir i have attched links of all scripts please check whther i am doing wrong